# Is it okay to write in my birthday invitation "please no tag-alongs"? Meaning do not bring extra guests? Thanks

Tags: sentence-meaning

I need if possible the use of a single word to state I don't want you  to bring extra people.

Comment: This is more a question of interpersonal skills than English learning.  Where did you get the word "tag-along" My guess is that you found it in a dictionary, is that right? Why do you have doubts about this?  Are you asking about meaning, or being polite?

Comment: That's perfect! You could also say ‘no [plus ones](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plus-one)’.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is clear.

Here is an example (from a girl scout cooking class not a party)

> Saturday, April 28, 2018
> 2:45pm-4:15pm
>
> Bring water bottle to cleanse palate
> Leaders and Parents are not permitted in the classroom. No tag-alongs ([source](https://chocologyunlimited.com/products/girl-scouts))

In terms of politeness, it might be better to speak to your friends to explain why you can't let them bring a partner (for example)